# Как убрать из списка предложенных адресов Страну и город и вставить в input при нажатии

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Вот код кастомного поиска:

```
let suggestView =  new ymaps.SuggestView('address', { provider: {
                suggest:(function(request, options){
                    return ymaps.suggest("Санкт-Петербург, " + request);
                })}
            });
```

К примеру в деливири Страна из списка не выводиться [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По хорошему вы должны геокодировать адрес и отобразить его на карте Яндекс, как этого требует их [пользовательское соглашение](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) для бесплатных ключей.
После этого ответ геокодера содержит отдельно и город, и улицу, и дом - компонуйте, как удобно.

Если вопрос пока только о сокращении строки, то стандартный **replace** вполне справится с вашей задачей. Просто отслеживайте событие выбора элемента списка:

```
  suggestView.events.add('select', function (e) {
    var addr = e.get('item').value
    document.getElementById('address').value = addr.replace('Россия, ','');
  })
```